# This is a question about Mips procedure error

Tags: mips

This is a question about Mips procedure error.

This is a Mips programming question.
I made the procedure f = (g + h)-(i + j), but when I ran the code with QTspim, an error message appeared in the syntax that outputs the result of this procedure. (The error message is'Exception 12 [Arithmetic overflow] occurred and ignored'.)

Why am I getting this error?

```
.data

a0: .word 1    #g=1, h=2, i=3, j=4, saved in $a0, $a1, $a2, and $a3
a1: .word 2
a2: .word 3
a3: .word 4

str1: .asciiz "The answer is "

.text


.globl main

leaf: 
    add  $t0, $a0, $a1   #Include g+h in register $t0
    add  $t1, $a2, $a3   #Include i+j in register $t1
    sub  $s0, $t0, $t1   #f = $t0-$t1 (g + h)-(i + j)
    add $v0, $s0, $zero  #returns f
   
    jr      $ra     

main:       
 
sub $sp, $sp, 0 #Create $sp space for local variable creation


li $v0, 4       
la $a0, str1
syscall 

jal leaf
lw $a0, 0($sp)  


li $v0, 1
syscall 

exit:
li      $v0, 10              # terminate program run and
syscall                      # Exit
```

Comment: You're clobbering a callee-saved register without saving/restoring it.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: By starting over.

Comment: How are you passing parameters to leaf?  I don't see it.

Comment: Don't name your global variables the same as register names, that's got to be super confusing for anyone include yourself and the assembler.

Comment: @EOF Does asking to restart mean to run QTsipm again? Or does it mean to add another phrase? If I need to add a phrase, what phrase should I add?(And I added a comment to the code) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You have a comment "#g=1, h=2, i=3, j=4, saved in $a0, $a1, $a2, and $a3" but there is no corresponding code to bring this comment to life.

Comment: @Erik Eidt Isn't'a0: .word 1'part of specifying variables in mips?

Comment: Sure, but why name your variables the same as MIPS registers, and then assume some magic is going to happen??

Comment: @Erik Eidt thank you for yoir advice. I'm not good at Mips, so I don't understand what you're talking about. Any simple examples or methods would be appreciated. – P35LH3G8E7

Comment: A label declares global variables, but global variables are not parameters!  In MIPS parameters are passed in registers, like `$a0`, `$a1`.  As long as you're naming your global variables with the same names a MIPS registers, there's going to be ongoing confusion, possibly hopeless.  So change the names of your global variables from `a0`, `a1`, to something domain oriented, like `f`, `g`, `h`.  Then maybe you'll see that you have to actually do something to get those variables into the parameter registers.  For reference search for MIPS code with function calls to see parameter passing.